# How ColdFusion framework ONE making view function available in views

Tags: coldfusion, fw1

I am wondering how framework one (fw1) making `view()` function available in views, like ColdFusion in built functions?

For example, in the below code , the `view()` function can be called like any ColdFusion in built functions. How fw1 making it possible?

```
#view(‘components/contact’)#
```

The function `view()` has been defined in ***/framework/one.cfc***

Answer (score 1):

`Application.cfc` extends `one.cfc`. Every view is executed in the context of the `OnRequest` method and can therefore access these methods.

From the [documentation](https://framework-one.github.io/documentation/#your-first-fw1-application)

> FW/1 itself consists of a single CFC: framework.one, i.e., framework/one.cfc. Your Application.cfc will extend that

Comment: one.cfc does not extend Application.cfc

Comment: Actually, application.cfc should extend one.cfc